# How to retrieve session value and do a check in other page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

```
 reader = server.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, getPermissionlistQuery, param);
        var results = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            results.Add(reader["permissionName"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        Session.Add("Permissions", results);
```

I am adding results to the session, how can I retrieve it in another page.

results  is a list of values

```
var permissionList = Session["Permissions"];         
        string check = "Create Groups";
        if (permissionList.Any(item => item.Equals(check)))
        {
            // results contains the value in check 
        }
```

and I want to check whether the permission is available in the Permission list but the if statement is throwing a error

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What part of "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" in the tag description for `asp` did you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Change bottom code to this:

```
IList<String> collection = (IList<String>) Session["Permissions"];

string check = "Create Groups";

if (collection.Any(item => item.Equals(check)))
{
   // results contains the value in check 
}
```

Also, reference:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

[image]

Comment: Fixed your code for you. Thanks for the reply, it caught my attention :).

Answer (score 1):

Just call `String value = (String)Session["Key"];` to get the value

`Session["Key"]` will pull the value in session for that key. If the key doesn't exist it will return Null.

You may want to read up on [ASP.NET Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx) as well.

### Update

In response to your edit, ensure you have [references to Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546156.aspx) for your project. Any is a Linq extension.

Comment: @John updated the answer. Any is an extension method added by Linq. Ensure you have System.Core.dll as a referenced assembly for your project and a using System.Linq; statement at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permissionList is getting populated i.e. the code to pull data from session is working fine. If this wouldn't have been the case, then you would have received NullReference exception.

My guess here is that the real culprit is "var" keyword. When you pull PermissionList from session, it is retrieved as an "Object". Try explicitly casting the permissionList object i.e.

```
List<string> permissionList = Session["Permissions"];
```

or

```
var permissionList = (List<string>)Session["Permissions"];
```